# Unnatural bold Chinese characters in Wordpress

Tags: firefox, webfonts

Some Chinese characters on my website renders in Bold. I have no styles attached or elements within the `<p>` element. This happends only on FireFox

I tried setting  `content-language` to

```
 <meta content="ch" http-equiv="content-language">
```

and also tried adding the font `SimSun` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754602/chinese-characters-are-rendering-in-bold)

Can you guys please check this and let me know your thoughts [here](http://moneyandme.com.au/chinese/)

Comment: This has most likely nothing to do with the `content-language` (and much less with the `content-type` header, which you tagged this with – removed), but simply with the font that is used and how Firefox renders it. Try a different font.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. I tried many fonts and currently have `KozGoPro-Regular-AlphaNum` on my site. Looks like its not the font itself, that why I tried different headers with no luck

Comment: There’s a bug report for this: [Bug 677919 - Inconsistent rendering of Chinese characters](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=677919)

Comment: wow. Didnt know its a browser bug. Thanks @CBroe